# How to extract the adjacency matrix associated with a subgraph defined by FindPath

Tags: matrix, graphs-and-networks, code-request

For a directed graph `g`, one can obtain its adjacency matrix as:

```
SeedRandom[3];
g = RandomGraph[{10, 20}, DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
AdjacencyMatrix[g] // MatrixForm
```

Then, a subgraph of `g` defined by all the pathways from vertex 6 to 4 is:

```
fp = FindPath[g, 6, 4, Infinity, All]
hfp = HighlightGraph[g, Subgraph[g, fp, VertexLabels -> "Name"]]
```

I want to find the adjacency matrix of `hfp`, showing the highlighted edges in `hfp` in a 10 by 10 matrix (the size of the original digraph `g`).

Comment: Have you tried `PathGraph`? Like this: ```pgs = PathGraph /@ fp;``` You can then get the matrices for all paths `AdjacencyMatrix /@ pgs` and combine those. Cycles won't be preserved though.

Comment: Also what's wrong with just `sg // AdjacencyMatrix` where `sg = Subgraph[g, fp, VertexLabels -> "Name"];` ?

Comment: @flinty: Both of your suggestions generate a `(5,5) AdjacencyMatrix`. However, I want to create a `(10,10) Adjacency Matrix` (the size of the original directed graph) which incorporates the paths generated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
am = AdjacencyMatrix[Graph[VertexList @ g, EdgeList @ Subgraph[g, fp]]];

am // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Answer (score 5):

For a subgraph of `g` defined by all the pathways from vertex 6 to vertex 4, find the adjacency matrix that represents only the edges of the subgraph of the paths.

```
SeedRandom[3];
g = RandomGraph[{10, 20}, DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabels -> "Name"];
fp = FindPath[g, 6, 4, Infinity, All];
```

We can find the edges of `g` that are not in `Subgraph[g, fp]` using `Complement[EdgeList[g], EdgeList[Subgraph[g, fp]]]`, then remove these edges from `g` using [`EdgeDelete`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeDelete.html). The adjacency matrix of `g2` is the matrix of `g` with only the edges of the subgraph.

```
g2 = EdgeDelete[g, Complement[EdgeList[g], EdgeList[Subgraph[g, fp]]]];
MatrixForm[m = WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[g2]]
```

$$
{\small\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)}
$$

```
Sort@EdgeList[Subgraph[g, fp]] === EdgeList[g2]
(* True *)
```